# How to perform specific operations according to item's position in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get my code to perform different tasks for an item depending on where it is positioned in a list.

```
for item in list:
  if item #list pos == 2:
    #do something
  elif item # list pos == 1
```

Comment: Use `enumerate`.

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(list):...`

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Other than that you can simply check the position of the number with `enumerate()` as in `for i, item in enumerate(L): # rest of your code ` Also don't use list as variable name.

Comment: would be helpful if you can demonstrate what you have tried to achieve this and where you are stuck. Otherwise it seems a low quality post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`

```
for idx, item in enumerate(my_list):
  if idx == 2:
    # do something
  elif idx == 1
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,value in enumerate(list):
   list[i]= #do something
```

> where **i** will the position of element of list and **value** will be the value on that position in list